# Checkbox retornando null para o controller springboot e thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

estou com uma grade de numeros e eu quero selecionar esses numeros e mandar para uma lista no backend porem eu seleciono os numeros e ele vai para lista NULL.

aqui esta meu codigo html

[[${evento}]]

```
             <input type="hidden" name="numeroEsc" id="numeroEsc">
             
                     <!-- Formulário inscrição -->
    <section class="page-section" id="passo1" style="padding-top:100px" >
        <div class="container">
            <div layout:insert="~{fragments/Mensagem}"></div>
            <div layout:insert="~{fragments/MensagemErro}"></div>
            

            <div class=" row">
            
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-8">
                 <h3 class="text-muted text-center" style="margin-top: 0px;">Selecione um número de inscrição</h3>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">             
                    <span class="btn btn-primary">Disponível</span>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" disabled="">Indisponível</button>
                </div>
            
           
           
            <!-- Número da inscrição -->
                 
               
               
                <div th:each="numero : ${numeros}" class="col-4 col-md-4 col-lg-1 text-center">
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover">
                        <label class="btn1 btn-primary1">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="itensVenda" name="itensVenda" th:field="${compraBingo.itensVenda}" th:value="${numero.codigo}" >
                            <span th:text="${numero.numero}"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
           
                
                
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" >enviar</button>
                </div>
           
           </div>
           
       </div>    
     </section>
</form>
</div>
```

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log("O DOM foi carregado");

  // Adiciona um evento de escuta para mudanças nas checkboxes
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      console.log("Checkbox mudou!");
      // Verifica se a checkbox está marcada e exibe seu valor no console.log
      if (this.checked) {
        console.log(this.value + ' está marcado');
      } else {
        console.log(this.value + ' está desmarcado');
      }
    });
  });

  console.log("Event listeners foram adicionados às checkboxes");
});

esse eh meu controller

@GetMapping("/compraBingo")
public ModelAndView nova(CompraBingo compraBingo) {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("site/compras/compraBingo");

```
        mv.addObject("pacotes", pacotes.findAll());
        mv.addObject("lotes", lotes.findAll());
        mv.addObject("numeros", quantidadeMaxInscricoes.findAllByOrderByNumeroAsc());
        mv.addObject("compraBingos", compraBingos.findAll());
        mv.addObject("cidades", cidades.findAll());
        if(eventos.findByAtivoTrue().isPresent()) {
            mv.addObject("evento", eventos.findByAtivoTrue().get().getNome());
        }
        mv.addObject("tipoDocumentos", TipoDocumento.values());
        
        return mv;
    }
    
    
    
    
    @PostMapping("/compraBingo/salvar")
    @ResponseBody
    public MyResponse salvarIndex(@ModelAttribute("compraBingo") CompraBingo compraBingo, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println("Salvar INDEX"+compraBingo);

        

        MyResponse my =new MyResponse();
         try {
             
             this.compraBingoService.salvar(compraBingo);
             my.setResposta("OK");
         } catch (Exception e) {
               // my.setError( e.getMessage());
             my.setResposta("OCUPADO");
         }
        
        return my;
    }
```

esse eh meu model
package br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "compra_bingo")
public class CompraBingo {

```
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long codigo;
  
    @Transient
    private Integer numeroEsc;
  
  
  @Size(max = 200, message = "O nome do participante deve conter no máximo 200 caracteres")
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String nome;
  
  
  private String email;
  
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String contato;
  
  private String cpf;
```

//      TESTE CPF BRA PY
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "tipo_documento")
private TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;

```
    private String endereco;
    
    private String numero;
    
    private String bairro;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cidade", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
    private Cidade cidade;
    
    
    private Boolean estrangeiro =false;
    
    @Column(name = "descricao_estrangeiro")
    private String descricaoEstrangeiro;
    
    @Size(min = 1, message = "Selecione pelo menos um grupo!")
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="bingo_compra", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_venda"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_bingo"))
    private List<ItensCompra> itensVenda;
    
    
    @Column(name = "status_pagamento")
    private Boolean statusPagamento;
    
    
  
  
  public boolean isNovo() {
        return this.codigo == null;
      }

      @PrePersist
      @PreUpdate
      private void toUpperCase() {
       this.nome = this.nome.toUpperCase();
      // this.dataNascimento = ConverteStringData(this.dataNascimentoString);
      }
```

}

package br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "itens_compra")
public class ItensCompra {

```
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long codigo;
  
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="produto", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
  private QuantidadeMaxInscricao quantidadeMaxInscricao;
  
  private int quantidade;

  private Double total;
```

}

package br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.service;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.exception.ImpossivelExcluirEntidadeException;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.model.CompraBingo;

import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.model.QuantidadeMaxInscricao;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.repository.CompraBingos;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.repository.Eventos;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.repository.QuantidadeMaxInscricoes;

@Service
public class CompraBingoService {

```
@Autowired
private CompraBingos compraBingos;

@Autowired
private Eventos eventos;

@Autowired
private QuantidadeMaxInscricoes quantidadeMaxInscricoes;

@Transactional
public void salvar(CompraBingo compraBingo) {
    System.out.println(".........................SERVICE"+compraBingo.getItensVenda());
    
    QuantidadeMaxInscricao  numero = quantidadeMaxInscricoes.findByEventoAndNumero(eventos.findByAtivoTrue().get(),compraBingo.getNumeroEsc()).get();
    
    numero.setStatus(false);
```

//      this.quantidadeMaxInscricoes.save(numero);
//      System.out.println(".........................teste numero"+numero);

```
    this.compraBingos.save(compraBingo);    
    
}


public void excluir(Long codigo) {
    try {
        compraBingos.deleteById(codigo);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
      throw new ImpossivelExcluirEntidadeException("Não foi possível excluir, há empresaService associados");
    }
  }

public Object buscarTodos() {
    return compraBingos.findAll();      
}

public Optional<CompraBingo> buscarInscricao(Long codigo) {     
    return compraBingos.findById(codigo);
}
```

}
aki esta meu service
package br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.service;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.exception.ImpossivelExcluirEntidadeException;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.model.CompraBingo;

import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.model.QuantidadeMaxInscricao;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.repository.CompraBingos;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.repository.Eventos;
import br.gov.pr.guaira.festadasnacoes.repository.QuantidadeMaxInscricoes;

@Service
public class CompraBingoService {

```
@Autowired
private CompraBingos compraBingos;

@Autowired
private Eventos eventos;

@Autowired
private QuantidadeMaxInscricoes quantidadeMaxInscricoes;

@Transactional
public void salvar(CompraBingo compraBingo) {
    System.out.println(".........................SERVICE"+compraBingo.getItensVenda());
    
    QuantidadeMaxInscricao  numero = quantidadeMaxInscricoes.findByEventoAndNumero(eventos.findByAtivoTrue().get(),compraBingo.getNumeroEsc()).get();
    
    numero.setStatus(false);
```

//      this.quantidadeMaxInscricoes.save(numero);
//      System.out.println(".........................teste numero"+numero);

```
    this.compraBingos.save(compraBingo);    
    
}


public void excluir(Long codigo) {
    try {
        compraBingos.deleteById(codigo);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
      throw new ImpossivelExcluirEntidadeException("Não foi possível excluir, há empresaService associados");
    }
  }

public Object buscarTodos() {
    return compraBingos.findAll();      
}

public Optional<CompraBingo> buscarInscricao(Long codigo) {     
    return compraBingos.findById(codigo);
}
```

}
alguem poderia me ajudar por favor